# onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) keeps on executing continuously

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, face-detection

I am creating an application capture image as it detect the face and I am able to achieve that, but only one issue the OnFaceDetection function of FaceDetectionListener is keep on executing even if there is no face in-front of camera. I am pasting my code.

```
mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(new Camera.FaceDetectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
            try {
                if (lastCaptureTiume + 10000 <= System.currentTimeMillis() || !faceCaptured) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                    lastCaptureTiume = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    faceCaptured = true;
                }   
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
    }
});
```

The issue is it is keep on takeing picture although there is no face in front of camera.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is different for different devices For my Note 3 onFaceDetection keeps on executing even without face and for nexus phone its performing perfectly.
Well I didn't got any other solution so I put a face check condition.

```
     if (faces != null && faces.length > 0) {
        //Do code here
     }
```